# C# Object Serialization to XML namespace and prefix in child element only

Tags: c#, xml

How to get a namespace set at a child level element when serializing an object to XML with C#?

The XML I want to end up with this as the XML output:

```
<clsPerson>
  <FirstName>Jeff</FirstName>
  <MI>J</MI>
  <LastName>Jefferson</LastName>
  <ns1:Addresses xmlns="www.whatever.co.uk">
    <Home>Here</Home>
    <Work>There</Work>
  </Addresses>
</clsPerson>
```

The code I'm using is mostly taken from other questions, and is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class clsPerson
{
   public string FirstName;
   public string MI;
   public string LastName;

   [XmlElement(Namespace = "www.whatever.co.uk")]
   public clsPlaces Addresses; 

       public clsPerson()
       {
         clsPlaces clsPlaces = new clsPlaces();
       }
 }

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "")]
public class clsPlaces
{
public string Home { get; set; }
public string Work { get; set; }
   }

class class1
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    clsPerson p = new clsPerson();
    var xml = "";
    p.FirstName = "Jeff";
    p.MI = "J";
    p.LastName = "Jefefrson";
    p.Addresses = new clsPlaces();
    p.Addresses.Home = "Here";
    p.Addresses.Work = "There";

    var emptyNamepsaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] {       XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

   emptyNamepsaces.Add("ns", "www.whatever.co.uk");

    using (var stream = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, p, emptyNamepsaces);
        xml =  stream.ToString();
    }

       Console.WriteLine(xml)
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The above gives:

```
<clsPerson xmlns:ns="www.whatever.co.uk">
  <FirstName>Jeff</FirstName>
  <MI>J</MI>
  <LastName>Jefefrson</LastName>
  <ns:Addresses>
    <Home>Here</Home>
    <Work>There</Work>
  </ns:Addresses>
```

How would I get the  xmlns on the  element only? I have tried everything I can see search stackoverflow, and not been able to find/understand the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove this - adding the namespace will ensure the prefix gets added to the root:

```
emptyNamepsaces.Add("ns", "www.whatever.co.uk");
```

The declaration for addresses will get added automatically.  You also need to remove the empty namespace from `clsPlaces`, else the namspaces for `Home` and `Work` will be incorrect:

```
public class clsPlaces
{
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public string Work { get; set; }
}
```

The output will then look like this:

```
<clsPerson>
  <FirstName>Jeff</FirstName>
  <MI>J</MI>
  <LastName>Jefefrson</LastName>
  <Addresses xmlns="www.whatever.co.uk">
    <Home>Here</Home>
    <Work>There</Work>
  </Addresses>
</clsPerson>
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wBNIal) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, this is really close to what I need, but `code`<Address>`code` needs to have the prefix of ns. How can I add that to only to address? (I'm not all to sure of the semantics of XML, and if this is important. I'm also unsure how compliant the system receiving this request will be, so really want to make this the same as an example I've been given.

Comment: @Richie unfortunately that isn't really possible without getting down into hand coding the serialisation. I would point out that your current output and my amended output are semantically equivalent to your example output, so any parser shouldn't have any problem with either.